# How can I extend ApplicationUser in ASP.NET Identity but with properties that can be null?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I would like to extend Application User.  Here's an example:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> 
    GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this,  DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
```

I tried this but it seems like when I login if any of these properties is set to a null in the database then when the /Token call is made it returns with an error.

Can someone tell me. Do I need to make a change to the way these properties are set here or in another place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, a simple solution to your problem could be to create a [nullable type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx). Can you please share what you would like to do? Create a custom identity provider, for example?